# How to Set Type in Expression.Property for JObject

Tags: c#, linq, lambda, json.net, expression-trees

I am trying to generate an Expression Tree. I have JSON Data which i have taken into JOject.
This is how my `firstRecord` looks like:-

```
{
  "Name": "JOHN",
  "Code": "112631.1"

}
```

CODE:-

```
   var reportArr = (JArray)(data["reportData"]);
   var firstRecord=reportArr.FirstOrDefault();//sample data given above
   Type classType = firstRecord.GetType();// Type is Of JObejct.
   ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(classType, "lambdaKey");
   var fun = Expression.GetFuncType(classType, typeof(object));
   var menuProperty = Expression.Property(parameter, "Name");//Throwing error
```

Error Message is :-

```
 Instance property 'Name' is not defined for type 'Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject'
```

How can i get MemberExpression from Expression.Property with JOject.

Comment: I suppose you need to use indexer instead of direct Name property as `JObject` doesn't have that property. So you should generate expression that will do `(string)firstRecord["Name"]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JObject` is a dynamic type and does not provide typed properties like regular types.

As usual with expressions, you can start from writing a compile time expression:

```
Expression<Func<JObject, object>> expr = item => ((JValue)item.Property("Name").Value).Value;
```

and examine what's inside using the debugger Locals/Watch window.

In this case, it would be something like this

```
var item = Expression.Parameter(typeof(JObject), "item");
var body = Expression.Property(
    Expression.Convert(
        Expression.Property(
            Expression.Call(item, "Property", null, Expression.Constant("Name"))
            , "Value")
        , typeof(JValue))
    , "Value");
var expr = Expression.Lambda<Func<JObject, object>>(body, item);
```